# Condition depending other field

Tags: plone, zope, template-tal, zpt

i have 2 fields (fieldA and fieldB)

what i want :
- if the fieldA contains something then the fieldB should not be displayed

what i try :

```
<span tal:replace="here/getFieldA" />

<span tal:omit-tag="here/getFieldA"  tal:replace="here/getFieldB" />
```

so it doesn't work

thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is [`tal:condition`](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#condition-conditionally-insert-or-remove-an-element), possibly combined with the [`not:`](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#tales-not-expressions) and [`exists:`](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#tales-exists-expressions) prefixes:

```
<span tal:replace="here/getFieldA" />

<span tal:condition="not:exists:here/getFieldA" tal:replace="here/getFieldB" />
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`|` operator](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#id31), which acts like an if operator, testing existence of the first element. If it doesn't exist, it'll use the next expression, and so on:

```
<span tal:replace="here/getFieldA | here/getFieldB" />
```

The [`tal:omit-tag`](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#omit-tag-remove-an-element-leaving-its-contents) attribute means something very different. If it's expression evaluates to `True`, then the tag, and only the tag itself, is omitted from the output. This is best illustrated with an example:

```
<span tal:omit-tag="">
    <i>This part will be retained</i>
</span>
```

Rendering that piece of pagetemplate results in:

```
<i>This part will be retained</i>
```

The surrounding `<span>` tag was omitted, but the contents were preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<span tal:condition="here/getFieldA"  tal:replace="here/getFieldB" />
```

The Zope Page Templates Reference http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a refinement of the original answer, based on the comments:

```
<tal:block 
    tal:define="zone here/getZoneintervention;
                thezone python:', '.join(zone);
                dep here/getDepartements;
                thedep python:', '.join(dep)">

   <span tal:condition="zone" tal:replace="thezone" /> 
   <span tal:condition="not:zone" tal:replace="thedep" /> 

</tal:block>
```

Comment: `or` is not the right description for the pipe operator. It only looks at the next element if the element before the `|` is not found (so raises `NotFound`, `AttributeError` or `KeyError`. If the expression before the pipe returns a boolean `False` (or equivalents such as `None` or `[]` or `0`) then that's what gets returned!

Comment: I recently had to help someone who had misunderstood the nature of the operator, because of incorrect interpretation. :-)

Comment: here is my complete code :

`<tal:block tal:define="zone here/getZoneintervention;
                       thezone python:', '.join(zone);
                       dep here/getDepartements;
                       thedep python:', '.join(dep)">

<span tal:replace="thezone | thedep" />

</tal:block>`
if the field Zoneintervention is empty nothing is displayed after

Comment: Martijn's comment explains why that happens. My example was dependent on here/getFieldA actually failing, not just returning false or an empty string. tal:condition combined with the "not:" preface should be your solution. If getZoneintervention always returns something, don't use "exists:" in your tests.